# How to get amount of the data cached by filesystem?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, systems-programming

I wondering how to get the size of data cached by the filesystem (on Linux) after the `write` syscall was invoked. This is needed in order to find out which filesystem is the best in data caching and should be chosen to be used on SSD devices to reduce device wear as much as possible.

The initial idea was to check the amount of data passed to write syscall using `strace` and compare it to the amount of data passed to the device using `iostat`, but I'm not sure if this approach is correct.

Comment: Given the endurance of modern SSDs, that's a strange reason for choosing a filesystem.

Comment: That SSD is going to be run for years as a part of the embedded system without the possibility to replace it with a new one.